# Spring automatically change the state of an object depending on the date

Tags: mysql, spring

I'm working on a spring web Application lately, it's for a medicale service.

the thing is, i want that after the meeting with a doctor is done, which means the meeting date is already have been passed, the application updates the database changing the meetings' states to "done", at least daily

does spring provides some feature like that?

also If there's a database solution( with a trigger or something ) i won't mind, i'm using MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use spring's schedulers to do some operations at fixed interval of time, sample code follows:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000, initialDelay = 5000)
    public void scheduleMethod() {
        System.out.println("ScheduledTasks.scheduleMethod() : " + new Date());
    }
}
```

for more details you can go through the spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

you can also do the same using quartz for more details http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example1

Comment: Thanks for the useful resoponse, i just have another question, does that component can be a service ?